# Assigning array inside object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have `cart` and `products` global variable.

Products can have multiple attributes.

Here is a code

```
var products = [
                  {
                    name: 'Table',
                    price: 200,
                    attributes: [
                                  {
                                    name: 'Height',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    default_value: '',
                                  },
                                  {
                                    name: 'Width',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    default_value: '',
                                  }
                                ],
                  },
                  {
                    name: 'Chair',
                    price: 150,
                    attributes: [
                                  {
                                    name: 'Height',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    default_value: '',
                                  },
                                  {
                                    name: 'Width',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    default_value: '',
                                  },
                                  {
                                    name: 'Company',
                                    type: 'text',
                                    default_value: ''
                                  }
                                ],
                  }
              ];

var cart = {
  products: [],
};

//console.log('Initial cart',cart);

//add product to cart
let p = Object.assign({},products[0]);
cart.products.push(p);

//console.log('First cart', cart);
//change price
cart.products[0].price = 20;
//console.log('products',products);
//console.log('second cart',cart);

//change attribute of product
cart.products[0].attributes[0].value = 5;
```

This code changes global `products` `value` attributes instead of cart attributes.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you can use lodash, try `lodash.cloneDeep`. you are copying only the keys, and each none primitive value (e.g object) is passed by pointer (and not cloned). clone deep is one option, another option, which also do the job `p = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products[0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> `Object.assign()` copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

And as `products[0]` is an object in your data that's why you are facing this shallow copy issue

Instead you can use

```
let p = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products[0]));
```

```js
var products = [{
        name: 'Table',
        price: 200,
        attributes: [{
                name: 'Height',
                type: 'text',
                default_value: '',
            },
            {
                name: 'Width',
                type: 'text',
                default_value: '',
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Chair',
        price: 150,
        attributes: [{
                name: 'Height',
                type: 'text',
                default_value: '',
            },
            {
                name: 'Width',
                type: 'text',
                default_value: '',
            },
            {
                name: 'Company',
                type: 'text',
                default_value: ''
            }
        ],
    }
];

var cart = {
    products: [],
};

//console.log('Initial cart',cart);

//add product to cart
let p = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products[0]));
 
cart.products.push(p);

//console.log('First cart', cart);
//change price
cart.products[0].price = 20;
console.log('products',products);
console.log('second cart',cart);
```

Comment: Then what should I do? @GeorgeBailey

Answer (score 0):

You create only shallow copy with Object.assign, which leads to accessing the same objects in a memory through copied reference.

If I need to modify object that is passed by reference or is global and I dont want to mutate it for all other functions/parts of the code, I use this: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

```
let p = _.cloneDeep(products[0]);
```